# Do the terms of an infinite series constitute a countable set?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Given an infinite series (e.g. trigonometric expansion, exponential, whatever)  $\sum_{\infty}T_{n}$, were one to consider the terms of this series as the members of a set $S$, it is obvious that the set would be an infinite one (given that the terms come from an infinite series in the first place).

My question is would this set be considered countably infinite or uncountably infinite?

My guess is toward countably infinite, since each member of the set (i.e. term $T_{m}$ in the series) can be uniquely mapped to the corresponding real number $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and thus there exists a bijection between the set $S$ and $\mathbb{Z}$, and hence by the definition of a [countable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set), the infinite series should be countably infinite. But being painfully aware of my tendency to jump to easy conclusions, I would like someone better educated to confirm this.

Comment: Your guess is a solid one.

Comment: Usually infinite series $\sum_{s \in S} f(s)$ are defined for countable $S$. However, there are ways to define uncountable sums too. For example, if all terms are non-negative, then any infinite sum can be defined as the supremum of all finite sums.

Comment: @Arthur many thanks for confirming :-)

Comment: @Crostul could you please give an example of an uncountably infinite series/sum to help me understand better?

Comment: Integrals can be interpreted as uncountable sums.

Comment: @Arthur Integrals is a good example for an uncountable sum indeed (this applies to both the Riemann and the Lebesgue definitions if I understand correctly). But there are no instances of "infinite series" being uncountable...right?

Comment: @Arthur No, definitely not. Every single integral (Riemann, Darboux, Lebesgue,...) is based on "countable". $\sigma$-algebras were invented to describe uncountable sets by countably many operations.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I'm not saying it's technically correct according to any standard definition of integration, but you can't deny that $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$ is often intuitively thought of as the sum of area of infnitely many rectangles, one for _each number in the interval_ $[0,1]$. There are uncountably infinitely many of those. Besides, the actual definitions like Riemann, Darboux and Lebesgue actually never touch infinite sums at all. They are all defined from finite sums.

Comment: @Arthur No. Riemann sums are based on partitions (into your "rectangles"), not on "each number in the interval". Those are necessarily countable, as non-trivial intervals contain at least one rational point. I'm not responsible for the "intuition" of uninformed people, I'm speaking of the most hated concept at MSE (definitions).

Comment: @ProfessorVector Apparently definitions are hated with good reason; even you, who seem to be very for the concept, can't get them straight. At no point in the deifnition of Riemann integration are we using any infinite sums or partitions. And just because you don't like to use intuition doesn't mean that the same is true for every informed person. I can promise you that the "infinitely many, infinitely narrow rectangles" interpretation is quite prevalent. But if you think theoretical physicists, among others, are "uninformed", then that's on you.

Comment: @Arthur Lol. "Reading" seems to be hated for the same reason: tell me where I said partitions are infinite. *You* claimed that it is the intuition of some people that includes *every* real number ("each number in the interval"). I said they're countable, and finite sets are countable, are they not?

Comment: @ProfessorVector I really need to start remembering that "countable" includes finite for most other people (which makes sense from the word itself, but has always seemed strange to me as a concept). So yeah, although I think definitions are nice on general principle, there are some definitions where I disagree with the specifics.

Comment: @Arthur That's not the point. Imagine $\int^1_0x\,dx=1/2$ (say) as an uncountable sum ("for all $x\in[0,1]$"?). How many summands can be $\ge1/2$? Not more than $1$. How many $\ge1/4$? Not more than $2$.... How many $>0$? Not more than countably many. Now identify the countably many summands in that integral really contributing to the sum, please.

Comment: @ProfessorVector And that inability of yours to look past the formalities is _exactly_ my point. There are uncountably many contributing terms, and each of them are infinitely small, being the area of a line segment. It's not _supposed_ to be rigorous. That doesn't mean that it doesn't make sense. After all, it took millennia from the first time this idea took form until we realised that the formalities behind it aren't as simple as one might intuitively think, and yet we still managed to make great use of it. You seem to think it useless, and I think you couldn't be further from the truth.

Comment: @Arthur This is stack exchange **mathematics**. Feel free to discuss non-mathematics anywhere you please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you construct from a formal series $\sum_{i \in I} T_i$ a set $S = \{T_i | i \in I\}$.

Then the cardinal of $S$ is less than or equal to the cardinal of $I$, almost by definition.

In particular, if $I = \mathbb{N}$, or if $I = \mathbb{Z}$, then $S$ is countable.

PS : note that it is not necessarily infinite, for instance if $T_i = T_j$ for any $i,j \in I$, then $|S|=1$.